# Regular expression with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following code in java script

```
    var regexp = /\$[A-Z]+[0-9]+/g;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (regexp.test("$A1")) {
            console.log("Matched");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Unmatched");
        }
    }
```

Please run it on your browser console. It will print alternative **Matched** and **Unmatched**. Can anyone tell the reason for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7331753/1917390

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After call `test` on a string, the `lastIndex` pointer will be set after the match.

```
Before:
$A1
^

After:
$A1
   ^
```

and when it comes to the end, the pointer will be reset to the start of the string.

You can try '$A1$A1', the result will be

```
Matched
Matched
Unmatched
...
```

This behavior is defined in 15.10.6.2, [ECMAScript Language Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

> Step 11. If global is true,
>   a. Call the [[Put]] internal method of R with arguments "`lastIndex`", e, and true.

Comment: Hi Hoacheng +1 for your good answer. But still I am confused with the concept. can you please describe it in simple way.

Comment: @Workonphp There's a pointer `lastIndex` when using `g` flag on your RE, which means the place matched last time will be stored. This behavior causes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've narrowed your code down to a simple example:

```
var re = /a/g, // global expression to test for the occurrence of 'a'
s = 'aa';     // a string with multiple 'a'

> re.test(s)
  true
> re.lastIndex
  1
> re.test(s)
  true
> re.lastIndex
  2
> re.test(s)
  false
> re.lastIndex
  0
```

**This only happens with global regular expressions!**

From the [MDN documentation on `.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> As with `exec` (or in combination with it), `test` called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use the global flag `g`, every time you called `.test`, the `.lastIndex` property of the regex object is updated.

If you don't use the `g` flag, then you could see the different result.

Answer (score 0):

The 'g' in line one is not correct, you are not performing a substitution here, but a match, remove it and you will get your expected behavior.

var regexp = /\$[A-Z]+[0-9]+/g;  should be: var regexp = /\$[A-Z]+[0-9]+/

Comment: The global modifier is not only useful for substitutions.